# The initial state or constants of an RNN layer cannot be specified with a mix of Keras tensors and non-Keras tensors

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, encoder-decoder

As we know the decoder takes the encoder hidden states as the initial state ...

```
encoder_output , state_h, state_c = LSTM(cellsize,  return_state=True)(embedded_encoder_input)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_lstm = LSTM(cellsize,  return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs, state_dh, state_dc = decoder_lstm(embedded_decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
```

Assume I want to replace the initial state of the decoder to be encoder_output and features from me from other resources

```
encoder_states = [encoder_output , my_state]
```

But I face the following error:

> ValueError: The initial state or constants of an RNN layer cannot be
>   specified with a mix of Keras tensors and non-Keras tensors (a "Keras
>   tensor" is a tensor that was returned by a Keras layer, or by `Input`)

Although I print state_h & stat_c & encoder_output & my_state, all have the same type and shape, example:

> ```
> state_h:  Tensor("lstm_57/while/Exit_2:0", shape=(?, 128), dtype=float32)
> my_state:  Tensor("Reshape_17:0", shape=(?, 128), dtype=float32)
> ```

What am I understanding that it will not accept inputs not produced from the previous layer, and as Keras tensor?

**Update**

After convert tensor to Keras tensor, The new error:

> ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from
>   `keras.layers.Input`. Received: Tensor("Reshape_18:0", shape=(?, 128),
>   dtype=float32) (missing previous layer metadata).

Comment: The string version of Keras layers print the underlying tensor so you won't see a different. Where are you getting `my_state` from?

Comment: I can see that, but where do you get it from? Is it created using `tf` or is it passed from somewhere else, do you generate it, is it an input? Depending on it's source you would need the appropriate wrapper for Keras.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mixed tensorflow tensor and keras tensor. Although the results of `state_h` and `my_state` are tensor, they are actually different. You can use `K.is_keras_tensor()` to distinguish them. An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import LSTM,Input,Lambda

my_state = Input(shape=(128,))
print('keras input layer type:')
print(my_state)
print(K.is_keras_tensor(my_state))

my_state = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,128),dtype=tf.float32)

print('\ntensorflow tensor type:')
print(my_state)
print(K.is_keras_tensor(my_state))

# you may need it
my_state = Lambda(lambda x:x)(my_state)
print('\nconvert tensorflow to keras tensor:')
print(my_state)
print(K.is_keras_tensor(my_state))

# print
keras input layer type:
Tensor("input_3:0", shape=(?, 128), dtype=float32)
True

tensorflow tensor type:
Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 128), dtype=float32)
False

convert tensorflow to keras tensor:
Tensor("lambda_1/Identity:0", shape=(?, 128), dtype=float32)
True
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful and slove the first part of the problem .. still the second part problem "ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `keras.layers.Input`. Received: Tensor("Reshape_16:0", shape=(?, 128), dtype=float32) (missing previous layer metadata)."

Comment: @noor I don't quite understand this error.  What line of code does this error occur?  Can you provide more code in question?

Comment: @noor What's your `imgs_features` in `enc_dec_model = Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs,imgs_features, decoder_inputs], output=decoder_outputs)`? Should you use defined input layer `my_state`? In addition, the error seems to  be that `imgs_features` need ro be packaged as keras tensor. You may can refer https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4428

Comment: my_state define the input to receive imgs_features, and then convert my_state to Keras tensor .. I did that as you answered previously

Comment: @noor  I’m sorry to that my previous answer was just to illustrate the difference between the two, not as the input layer of the keras model. Because I think the tensorflow tensor you entered has been defined. According to what you said, I think you can pack your VGG16 prediction into `Lambda` layer instead of outputting tensorflow tensor out of the 
keras model and re-entering keras model.

Comment: Hmm, OK I will try that, Thank you.